# Strip newline from piped input

Tags: bash, readline

I've been setting up a script to work with haste-server. This takes piped or file input (`tail /var/log/messages | haste` and `haste < /path/to/file.txt`) and submits it to the server which then outputs a  in my terminal. See below:

```
#!/bin/bash
url="http://hastebin.com"
key="$(curl --silent --data-binary @/dev/fd/0 $url/documents | cut -d "\"" -f 4)"
echo "$url/$key"
```

It works just fine, however it adds a trailing new line to the input. How can I read `@/dev/fd/0` to remove the `\n` new line?

**Edit**: Here is my **completed script** for submitting a haste that trims the newline:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

url="http://hastebin.com"
data=$(< /dev/fd/0)
key="$(printf "%s" "$data" | curl -X POST -s --data-binary @- "$url/documents" | cut -d "\\"" -f 4)"
echo "$url/$key"
```

Comment: The output is `a`? Where is the newline in that? You re adding a newline with the `echo` command use `echo -n` instead.

Comment: @Anthon I'm looking to trim the input sent using curl, not the echo itself.

Comment: If the target is a terminal for display's sake, then you don't necessarily need to strip the newline - just add an escape at the end *(or before the end)* to either scroll the terminal or to eat the newline. You can `[ -t 1 ]` test for a terminal on stdout, and `tput` can help with the escapes. If you're having difficulty with the *eat the newline* thing, `printf '\033[@\n'` and have a look at how it behaves,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Avoiding newlines by 'echo' command

Instead of `echo`, use `echo -n`.

If that does not work (e.g. on OSX with `/bin/sh` as shell), or if you want make your script independent of which shell it runs under, use `/bin/echo -n` .

#### Avoiding newlines from "payload" (here: '$key')

Change the output newlines with `tr`, e.g.

```
echo "$url/$key" | tr '\n' '|'
```

Comment: And you, instead of space use "." at the end of your sentences. :-)

Comment: If you really want to make it portable, use `printf`; see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo for details.

Comment: I said it added a trailing new line to the input, meaning inside the curl when submitted. I have edited the code so that it works, submit a small file and you'll see what i mean when you visit the hastebin.